# Cannot find Widgets in test inside of Consumer Widget of Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-provider

I created the following Flutter test for my widget

```dart
testWidgets("", (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        ChangeNotifierProvider<SettingsViewProvider>(
          create: (context) => SettingsViewProvider(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            localizationsDelegates: [S.delegate],
            home: SettingsScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      );

      final textFormFieldFinder = find.byElementType(TextFormField);
      await tester.pump();
      expect(textFormFieldFinder, findsNWidgets(3));
    });
```

The widget is a stateful widget which uses a ChangeNotifierProvider and the Consumer surrounds a List of three "TextFormFields".

```dart
Consumer<State>(
   builder: (context, value, child)=> Column(
       children: [TextFormField(...), TextFormField(...), TextFormField(...)];
   )
)
```

> Expected: exactly 3 matching nodes in the widget tree
>
> Actual: _ElementTypeFinder:
>
> Which: means none were found but some were expected

Unfortunatly I receive that no widget is found in the widget tree.

Comment: The problem is likely to be somewhere between your Consumer and your Provider. Try executing `debugDumpApp` to see what happens

Comment: I added the `debugDumpApp` the result contains the three TextFormFields
Line 117 - Provider
Line 121 - TextFormField No.1
Line 165 - TextFormField No.2
Line 213 - TextFormField No.3

https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvXUDvgUDO2xiodjesQ8j8kwB_LQzQ?e=vr0GHS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As pointed out before, you should be using `find.byType` which is aimed at seaching Widgets rather than `find.byElementType` which deals with Elements.

Flutter has 3 UI building blocks:

**`Widgets`** (immutable) -> **`Elements`** (mutable) -> **`Render Objects`**
-- they are not inherited from one another, those are separate types of objects with different purposes.

`TextFormField` is a `Widget`, while it is being passed to `find.byElementType` which expects an ancestor of `Element`

Comment: I had the same problem when was testing with ```find.byKey('myKeyName')```

Answer (score 8):

it seems to be solved using:

```
final textFormFieldFinder = find.byType(TextFormField);
```

instead of:

```
final textFormFieldFinder = find.byElementType(TextFormField);
```